# Burninate the high school tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

I think we should burninate the [highschool](/questions/tagged/highschool) tag. The only correlation between the questions is that the user appears to be in a high school programming course, and it does not seem to tie in any way to actual programming.

Does anyone see any reason why it cannot be deleted/burninated?

Comment: Retagged a few and left the rest for closure/deletion.

Comment: It's already gone from all questions. Unless we think it needs to be blacklisted we're basically done.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image]: